# Visual Studio publishing to app store with Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I can't find any documentation on how to publish your app to the app store from Visual Studio? Is this a case of having to use Xamarin Studio once you are ready to submit your app?

It seems a bit odd that xamarin gives you the opportunity to use Visual Studio but then has absolutely no instructions on how to create a bundle to submit your app to the app store..

Any tips on how to do this with Visual Studio would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way of submitting to AppStore (or even TestFlight) from VS.

I believe that you can only submit builds to the App Store using Xcode or Application Loader. Both Mac programs.

Personally I make a release build in Visual Studio, and then click the 'Show IPA File In Build server' button.

If the buttons greyed out, right-click your iOS solution, select properties. Then go to 'iOS IPA Options' and check 'Build ad-hoc/enterprise package (IPA)'

Then I go to my Mac and start up Application Loader and drag the IPA file there.

Comment: This button is greyed out when I make an AppStore build? http://s29.postimg.org/cqhhbs5rr/bar.png. Is only clickable when i choose an ad-hoc build....

Comment: Are you able to submit to the App Store like this? I thought for aD-Hoc (instead of App Store) you would need a different provisioning profile

Comment: It's still your App Store profile. I've done this less than two weeks ago

Comment: It seems to work! I will upload to app store later. Thanks for your help with this!!