# What are the steps to publish a Xamarin.Forms iOS application to TestFlight?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, testflight

I have created the Development and Distribution profiles and certificates.
I'm able to build the `.ipa` using the development signing authority and the development profile but I am getting an error saying "No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile '{name}'".

Is there any ste-by-step guid available on creating and uploading a build to the `TestFlight` using `Xamarin.Forms` and `Visual Studio 2015`?

Comment: Use `application loader` with your ipa

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov what build configuration should be used to create the ipa? Can I use the `Ad-hoc` or should I be using the `AppStore`?

Comment: `AppStore` only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio publishing to app store with Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032529/visual-studio-publishing-to-app-store-with-xamarin)

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/testflight/

Comment: I just want to add that I am going through this nightmare right now and the docs EVERYWHERE (Apple and MS) are FAR from adequate.

Comment: @Sentinel I'd say that it works but there can be several unexpected issues in between